# Largest sum from absolute differences of N elements in an array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, dynamic-programming, absolute-value

This isn't really a homework, but rather a practice and optimization, but this seemed like the best section for this type of questions.

It is a dynamical programming issue, and it's the following:

-Given an *unsorted* array of N elements, pick K number of elements from it, such that their absolute difference is the largest.

An absolute difference is calculated between adjacent elements here. So if we have an array of 5 elements: 1 5 3 2 1, and k = 3, the absolute differences would be:

1 5 3 = |5-1| + |3-5| = 6

1 5 2 = |5-1| + |2-5| = 7

1 5 1 = [5-1| + |1-5| = 8

etc

With 1 5 1 being the largest and needed one with 8

What i've tried so far is solving this by finding all possible combinations of K numbers with a recursion and then returning the biggest(brute force).

This showed as a terrible idea, because when tried with an array of N=50 and k=25 for example, there are 1.264106064E+14 combinations.

The recursion i used is a simple one used for printing all K-digit integers from an array, just instead of printing them, keeping them in an array:

```
static void solve(int[] numbers, int k, int startPosition, int[] result) {
        if (k == 0) {
            System.out.println(absoluteDifferenceSum(result));
            return;
        }
        for (int i = startPosition; i <= numbers.length - k; i++) {
            result[result.length - k] = numbers[i];
            solve(numbers, k - 1, i + 1, result);
        }
    }
```

What I want to achieve is the optimal complexity (which i suppose can't be lower than O(n^2) here, but i'm out of ideas and don't know how to start. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, we can have a naive `O(n^2 * k)` formulation, where `f(i, k)` represents the best result for selecting `k` elements when the `i`th element is rightmost in the selection,

```
f(i, k) = max(
  f(j, k - 1) + abs(Ai - Aj)
)
for all j < i
```

which we can expand to

```
  max( f(j, k - 1) + Ai - Aj )
= Ai + max(f(j, k - 1) - Aj)

when Ai >= Aj
```

and

```
  max( f(j, k - 1) + Aj - Ai )
= -Ai + max(f(j, k - 1) + Aj)

when Ai < Aj
```

Since the right summand is independent of `Ai`, we can build a tree with nodes that store both `f(j, k - 1) - Aj`, as well as `f(j, k - 1) + Aj`. Additionally, we'll store in each node both maxes for each subtree. We'll need `O(k)` trees. Let's skip to the examination of the tree for `k = 2` when we reach the last element:

```
1

5 -> 4 -> (-1, 9)

3 -> 2 -> (-1, 5)

2 -> 3 -> (-1, 5)

3 -> (-3, 5)

tree for k = 2 so far:

   3 (-1, 5)
  /         \
2 (-1, 5)   5 (-1, 9)

1 is less than 3 so we first add -1
to the max for the right subtree
stored for f(j, k - 1) + Aj

-1 + 9 = 8
(note that this represents {1,5,1})

then we continue left in the tree
and compare 8 to a similar calculation
with node 2: -1 + 5 = 4
(note that this represents {5,2,1})
```

This way, we can reduce the time complexity to `O(n log n * k)` with space `O(n * k)`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, will try this!